# Shopware 6.5.7 fileSaver->persistFileToMedia doesn't work

Tags: shopware6

with Shopware 6.5.7.x my plugin stopped working. It worked on earlier versions of shopware. I am getting following error.

```json
code    "0"
status  "500"
title   "Internal Server Error"
detail  "Warning: getimagesize(/var/www/html/public/media/64/fd/a6/1701174382/localstorage im firefox.PNG): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory"
meta    Object { file: "/var/www/html/vendor/shopware/core/Content/Media/Metadata/MetadataLoader/ImageMetadataLoader.php", line: 24, trace: […] }
trace   [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
0   Object { file: "/var/www/html/vendor/shopware/core/Content/Media/Metadata/MetadataLoader.php", line: 33, function: "extractMetadata", … }
1   Object { file: "/var/www/html/vendor/shopware/core/Content/Media/File/FileSaver.php", line: 84, function: "loadFromFile", … }
2   Object { file: "/var/www/html/custom/plugins/my_plugin/src/Services/ImageWatermarkService.php", line: 341, function: "persistFileToMedia", … }
```

This is the code which makes backup of an original image

```php
    private function makeBackup(MediaEntity $image, string $suffix, Context $context)
   {
            $oldMediaId = $image->getId();
            $newMediaId = $context->scope(Context::SYSTEM_SCOPE, function (Context $context) use ($oldMediaId): string {
                $behavior = new CloneBehavior([
                    'mimeType' => null,
                    'fileExtension' => null,
                    'uploadedAt' => null,
                    'fileName' => null,
                    'fileSize' => null,
                    'metaData' => null,
                ]);

                $newMediaId = Uuid::randomHex();
                $this->mediaRepository->clone($oldMediaId, $context, $newMediaId, $behavior);

                return $newMediaId;
            });

            //$path = $this->urlGeneratorInterface->getRelativeMediaUrl($image); //this was working before 6.5.7.x

            $path = $image->getPath();

            try {
                $this->publicFileSystem->read($path);
                $stream = $this->publicFileSystem->readStream($path);
                $metaData = stream_get_meta_data($stream);
                $oldFileNameWithPath = $metaData['uri'];
            }catch (UnableToReadFile $e){
                    echo "[ERROR] File $path does not exists, can't backup.\n";
                    return 1;
            }

            $mimeType = mime_content_type($path);
            $fileExtension = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $fileSize = filesize($oldFileNameWithPath);
            $fileName = pathinfo($oldFileNameWithPath, PATHINFO_FILENAME) . $suffix. $newMediaId;
            $mediaFile = new MediaFile($oldFileNameWithPath, $mimeType, $fileExtension, $fileSize);

/*            dd($mediaFile,
                $fileName,
                $newMediaId,
                $context);*/


            $this->fileSaver->persistFileToMedia(
                $mediaFile,
                $fileName,
                $newMediaId,
                $context
            );

            return $newMediaId;
    }
```

If I uncomment `dd()` it shows data which looks fine

```json
1 in ImageWatermarkService.php on line 335:
Shopware\Core\Content\Media\File\MediaFile {#1353
  -fileName: "/var/www/html/public/media/64/fd/a6/1701174382/localstorage im firefox.PNG"
  -mimeType: "image/png"
  -fileExtension: "PNG"
  -fileSize: 20884
  -hash: null
}

2 in ImageWatermarkService.php on line 335:
"localstorage im firefox_old018c15f0ec80707c96259735150e89fe"

3 in ImageWatermarkService.php on line 335:
"018c15f0ec80707c96259735150e89fe"

4 in ImageWatermarkService.php on line 335:
Shopware\Core\Framework\Context {#1252
  #extensions: []
[...]
```

I think's it must be related to changes in paths https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/v6.5.7.0/UPGRADE-6.5.md. I removed old UrlGeneratorInterface,but it does not change anything.

Comment: Have you tried the MediaUrlGenerator? You just mentioned that u removed the UrlGeneratorInterface,

Comment: @Ezycod I think I don't need MediaUrlGenerator. I have absolute url $oldFileNameWithPath which does exists. I can check it by file_exists function. The problem is in the persistFileToMedia()

Comment: The path saved in the media doesn't seem to be correct, did you check if the file exists? You can regenerate the path with the MediaUrlGenerator

Comment: This is strange because it does exists before executing persistFileToMedia() but inside functions of persistFileToMedia() it's gone.